# No User Interface file created with iOS Project

Tags: ipad, xcode4, ios-simulator

I am getting started with iOS programming, and created a new project in XCode 4.2.1. However, I do not see .xib file in my project as expected. I tried added a new .xib file and build interface on it, but when I run my program, I see a blank white screen on the iPad Simulator. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this method in the appDelegate (and the name of the xib / strip out universal aspects of code if needed)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

or

choose a Single View Application from the templates you are offered when creating a new app

Comment: I am choosing a single view application, still i don't see the .xib file.

Comment: actually, in my version of xcode, instead of .xib r .nib file, there's a storyboard file, which has the interface builder. So my problem is fixed, thanks.